# Could you explain meaning of "getting hit on something" & "laid back" in this passage,please?

Tags: word-meaning

> In this week's Fashion Q&A, Cosmopolitan.com's style editor, Charles Manning, answers your questions about high heels versus flats, the best underwear for avoiding panty lines, and how to make denim on denim work for you.
>
> Q: I usually wear heels because I think they're sexier, but lately I've been going for casual drinks in flats and **getting hit on**. Is there something to a flat shoe that's enticing, and which ones should I be wearing?
>
> A: It's possible that guys see your flats and think, "Hey, she seems chill and low maintenance." Or that they are less intimidated than they might be if you had the added height a pair of heels would normally give you. It's also possible that they never noticed your shoes in the first place and were responding to something you were not even aware of. There's really no way of knowing.
>
> As sexy as high heels are, their real value lies in how they make you feel and how you project that feeling out into the world. If you feel cool, **laid back**, and confident, it doesn't really matter how high your heels are. And although there are not nearly as many fabulous flats in the world as there are fabulous heels, there is usually an appropriate flat equivalent for any high heels.

Answer (score 1):

To "get hit on" means to have guys expressing a sexual interest in you. You are the target of their "sexual advances".

To be "laid back" means to be calm and easygoing, not nervous or agitated; "centered" in your being; a synonymous slang term would be "mellow" or "chill".